# Ajax using jquery hanging page for real ?Help Plzz

Tags: jquery, ajax

my browser keeps on hanging while loading this code  ,can some assist me on my code ..I think calling done() function recursively  is hanging my page..I am appending that in my div block with id="insert2"

```
<script>
var html='';
$(document).ready(function(){
$.when(done()).done(function(){done();});
});
function updates2(){
$.getJSON("porthome2_.php",function(data){
$.each(data.result,function(){

      html+= '//some more div blocks';

    });

  });
}
function done(){
setTimeout(function(){updates2();},200);
$("#insert2").empty();
$('#insert2').append(html);
$('#insert2').hide().fadeIn(2000);
done();
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `done()` recursively?  If you have an infinite recursion then, yes, that will block the browser.  Just like an infinite loop would.  Does the problem go away if you remove the recursive call?

Comment: actually i want to always update  my page  so that  whenevr someone post it gets displayed immediately as facebook does

Comment: can u suggest some other way to connect it always to database

Comment: What does any of this have to do with connecting to a database?  Are you just asking how to perform an action at regular intervals?  That's what the `setInterval()` function in JavaScript is for.

Comment: Sir this is a feed page ,,i want insert a new div if some other user post something new without reloading the page ,,thats what i am doing by calling done() recursively ..but i know thats hanging the page so can u assist how to do so???plzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments on the question, it sounds like what you want to do is simply:

> Perform an action at a regular interval.  For example, every second.

If you want to perform an action every second, you'd do something like this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    // your action
}, 1000);
```

Whatever that action is doesn't really matter.  The purpose of the `setInterval` function is to take a function definition and a number of milliseconds and simply execute that function over and over, every X milliseconds.

In your comments you are talking about things like connecting to a database, displaying a `div`, etc.  That would all be encapsulated in the "action" that you want to execute.  Whatever it is you want to execute at regular intervals, you simply execute it in a function passed to `setInterval()`.

Comment: ok this seems to be fine by me ,,,ok let me try if this works

Comment: thanx ,,page got a little better ,,,,can u suggest me some jquery functions that will load the page when someone scrolls the page down or up

Comment: that would just make the experience much better